# Different answeres doing essentially the same method

Tags: r, bootstrap

I want to do a bootstrap in two ways and compute the estimated bias and variance. The dataset I use is named `Data` and it is just $n=100$ randomly generated gamma distributed numbers $(\Gamma(2,1/2))$. One way is by writing my own code:

```
N = 1800
bsM = vector("numeric", 1800L)
for (i in 1:N){         # Own code that approximates the distribution.
  x = sample(Data, 100, replace = TRUE)
  bsM[i] = mean(x)      # These are all bootstrap means thetaHat*
}

EstimatedBias = mean(bsM) - thetaHat
EstimatedVariance = sum((bsM-mean(bsM))^2)/(N-1)
```

I get the answers $\text{Bias}(\hat{\theta})\approx 0.0031$ and $\text{Var}(\hat{\theta})\approx 0.0261$.

Now I want to get close to the same results using `boot`-function in R:

```
library("boot")
fun = function(Data,i){
   return(mean(Data[i]))
}

B = boot(Data,fun,N)
print(B)

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP

Call:
boot(data = Data, statistic = fun, R = N)


Bootstrap Statistics :
original      bias    std. error
t1* 4.082139 0.003445815   0.5119067
```

The bias seems acceptable here, but getting an SE of $0.51$ means the estimated variance is $s^2=SE^2\cdot n \approx 26,01$ which is whopping 1000 times larger. I used this also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error.

I'm wondering if I'm meant to get this huge difference using these two methods or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to replicate your answers.

How did you calculate $Var(\hat \theta)$?

First method:

```
library(boot)
set.seed(1)
Data = rgamma(100, 2, 1/2)

N = 1800
bsM = vector("numeric", 1800L)
for (i in 1:N){
    x = sample(Data, 100, replace = T)
    bsM[i] = mean(x)
}

sd(bsM) # gives 0.2195808
```

Second method:

```
fun = function(Data,i){
    return(mean(Data[i]))
}

B = boot(Data, fun, 1800)
print(B)

# Bootstrap Statistics :
#     original     bias    std. error
# t1*  3.74735 0.01100607   0.2181928
```

So both methods are consistent.

The standard error is defined as the standard deviation of a statistic. When you do a bootstrap, you're actually obtaining samples *of the statistic*, in this case, the mean. So, the standard deviation of `bsM` is literally the standard error and squaring it gives you $Var(\hat \theta)$. This is exactly what `boot` does.

Comment: Ahh alright i see now. I thought there was still a difference between standard deviation and standard error even in this case. Thank you very much Aditya!